# How to set a basename for react-router Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How can I config the basename, or keep a path in url like `localhost:8000/app` and when I have to redirect to another Route the Router identify this `/app` as part of url and do not change it, this is my component structure.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
<Router history={browserHistory} >
  <Route component={App}>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer} />
    <Route path="apresentacao">
      <IndexRoute component={NameContainer} />
      <Route path="2" component={HsContainer} />
      <Route path="3" component={McContainer} />
      <Route path="4" component={MpvContainer} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using React Router v4, you can use the [`basename`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) prop of the `Router` component to change the base of your app.

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from "react-router";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory} basename="/app">
        <Route component={App}>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer} />
          <Route path="apresentacao">
            <IndexRoute component={NameContainer} />
            <Route path="2" component={HsContainer} />
            <Route path="3" component={McContainer} />
            <Route path="4" component={MpvContainer} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

If you are using React Router v3, you need to install the [`history`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) package separately and use the `useBasename` function.

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from "react-router";
import { useBasename } from 'history'

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={useBasename(() => browserHistory)({ basename: '/app' })}>
        <Route component={App}>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer} />
          <Route path="apresentacao">
            <IndexRoute component={NameContainer} />
            <Route path="2" component={HsContainer} />
            <Route path="3" component={McContainer} />
            <Route path="4" component={MpvContainer} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution but still didn't worked, the url still `localhost:8000` and nothing changed, by the way I'm using redux, I don't know if this matters to the solution.

Comment: @LeonardoAlves Looking more closely at the code in your question, it looks like you are using react router v3. Is that correct?

Comment: I tried this solution, but it gives me this error `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _history.useBasename) is not a function`,  I'm using `react-router v3.0.0` and `history v4.7.2`, is that right?

Comment: I tried with history v3 and now the error is gone but still not working.