# Why does docker nginx container not render react Route?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, react-router-dom

I have been searching online for an answer to this but Im not finding the exact answer to my question. I have a react app. It is able to be built and run outside of a container. I now want to dockerize the react app. I feel like I have done this before without a problem but now it is causing me issues. I build the image and run it locally. The app on some level serves up correctly because the header component appears and works fine as well as the footer. The parts that dont show up are all inside react Route components however the html even appears on the dom. As I can see it there in the console. Even though I cannot see anything but the header and footer in the browser window. If I click in the right place in the browser window, I can even drag an image onto the desktop. I can then view the image fine. This seems super weird to me. I feel like it must be some sort of nginx/docker react-router config issue.

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY docker/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

default.conf file from docker folder

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name frontend;

 location / {
   # This would be the directory where your React app's static files are stored at
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   try_files $uri /index.html;
 }
}
```

Any idea what is causing this problem and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is the url you are visiting the page from ? if you are hosting it in www.example.com/subpath, the you need to set basename="/subpath/" for the router.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51639352/how-to-set-a-basename-for-react-router-router/51639407

Comment: Hi @AntonioPantano I dont think this applies because I am using react-router-dom. When I try and do that I get that browserHistory is not supported on react-router-dom

Comment: If your page loads some html and there are no 404s when serving files then it's almost certainly a React config error, not Nginx. If it was Nginx then no files from the Build dir would be served.

Comment: Don't care about history. the relevant part is the `basename` attribute that you should add to your Router or BrowserRouter component. But this applies only if you accessing the website from a sub path of the domain.

Comment: @Dan I don't know an answer, but there is a weird `location` block in your nginx config where you did some reverse proxy setup but didn't use any `proxy_pass` directive at all! What is that `/services/m` route and how it should be served?

Comment: @IvanShatsky that was me trying something. it did not work. I have reverted it to how it was before. It is the same result and updated the post to include the current nginx file

Comment: @AntonioPantano ok. Thank you. But this does not apply. There is no subdomain involved. Thanks.

Comment: @Dan How is that `COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html` command works? Does it make a `/usr/share/nginx/html/build` folder with the `index.html` and all the assets inside? Then your root should be `root /usr/share/nginx/html/build;`, not the `root /usr/share/nginx/html;`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bug with react or maybe nginx or something I am not sure. But I had an animation in my App.css file. This animation was on all of the primary page components. When I removed that css then it worked. This is what the animation was. What was wierd was it worked when running on the local dev server. I was having trouble getting my commands straight and didnt ever run the build artifacts on the local dev server. So that would be something to try. But in any case. Use this animation cautiously with react and nginx.

```
@keyframes appear {
  from{opacity: 0%}
  to{opacity: 100%}
}
```

Comment: Im more of a backend/cloud fella these days. i feel like I remember from back in the day that opacity is dangerous to use. Maybe this is common knowledge i just forgot about.